# Double loop groups and cohomology

Tags: lie-algebras, loop-spaces, lie-algebra-cohomology, geometric-representation-theory

Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over $\mathbb{C}$ of Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.

What is the value of $H^{3}(\mathfrak{g}((t))((s)),\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: A simply-connected group? Or just connected?

Comment: What does $\mathfrak{g}((t))((s))$ mean in this context?

Comment: I put the most general assumption, but even the simply connected case would be interesting. In this context, $\mathfrak{g}((t))((s))=\mathfrak{g}\otimes_{k}k((t))((s))$.